# MySQL Matching two users based on preference

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

Alright what I need to accomplish is a bit complicated but I'll do my best to explain.
So I have a table like this:

> id || color || redOK || blueOK || yellowOK || greenOK || orangeOK
>
> 1-||----1---||----1-----||-----1-----||-------1------||------0------||------1------
>
> 2-||----3---||----1-----||-----0-----||-------1------||------1------||------1------
>
> 3-||----1---||----0-----||-----0-----||-------0------||------0------||------1------
>
> 4-||----5---||----1-----||-----1-----||-------0------||------1------||------1------
>
> 5-||----2---||----0-----||-----0-----||-------1------||------0------||------1------

In the color field, the numbers 1 - 5 represent a user's favorite color (1 for red, 2 for blue, 3 for yellow, 4 for green and 5 for orange). The redOK, blueOk, yellowOK, greenOK and orangeOK fields represent whether or not the user is willing to match with someone with a certain favorite color. In these fields, a 1 represents a yes and a 0 represents a no. So for example, the user with id=1's favorite color is red because their "color" field is 1, and they're willing to match with someone whose favorite color is red, blue, yellow, or orange, but not green, because the "greenOK" field is 0. So what I need to do is create a stored procedure that returns a query with users whose color and color preferences match a specific user's color and color preferences. So for example, the users with id's 1 and 2 would be a match because user 1 is red and user 2 has chosen that red is okay, and user 2 is yellow and user 1 has chosen that yellow is okay. On the other hand, users 3 and 2 would not be a match because even though user 3 is red and user 2 has chosen that red is okay, user 2 is yellow and user 3 has said that only orange is okay.

I've been thinking about this problem all day, but can't quite come up with a solution. My first thought was to use a SELECT INNER JOIN statement, but I'm not quite sure how since there are so many possible combinations? Then I tried creating a temporary table with a user's preferences and then using a cursor to iterate through those preferences while checking if the user's preferences match the target user's color but I also could not figure that out. Can you guys help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the table as is, there are only five combinations that dictate a match, which you would simply OR together in a join, in both directions a->b and a<-b:

```
select *
from myTable a
join myTable b on (
        (a.color = 1 and b.redOK = 1)
        or (a.color = 2 and b.blueOK = 1)
        or (a.color = 3 and b.yellowOK = 1)
        or (a.color = 4 and b.greenOK = 1)
        or (a.color = 5 and b.orangeOK = 1)
    ) and (
        (b.color = 1 and a.redOK = 1)
        or (b.color = 2 and a.blueOK = 1)
        or (b.color = 3 and a.yellowOK = 1)
        or (b.color = 4 and a.greenOK = 1)
        or (b.color = 5 and a.orangeOK = 1)
    )
where a.id <> b.id
```

Alternatively, you can change your schema, essentially unpivoting your data into a many-to-many table. For example:

```
id    okColor
1     1
1     2
1     3
1     5
2     1
2     3
2     4
2     5
```

In this case you can just join through this table:

```
select distinct a.id, b.id
from myTable a
join okColors aOK on a.id = aOK.id
join myTable b on aOK.okColor = b.color
join okColors bOK on bOK.id = b.id and a.color = bOK.okColor
where a.id <> b.id
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was really overthinking it. Unfortunately, the second solution won't work because the users have more than 1 option for what color to match with, but the first one works just fine!